# Image is not centered Bootstrap center-block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cant center my image in a panel provided by bootstrap:

[image]

This my html code for this:

```
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <a class="modals" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PatientDiagnosisModal"  href="">
                        <div class="panel-body"><img class="img-responsive  center-block" src="../img/diagnosis.png"></img></div>
                        <div class="panel-footer"><center>Patient Diagnosis</center></div></a>
                        </div>
                  </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <a class="modals" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PatientDiagnosisModal"  href="">
                        <div class="panel-body"><img class="img-responsive  center-block" src="../img/diagnosis.png"></img></div>
                        <div class="panel-footer"><center>Patient Diagnosis</center></div></a>
                        </div>
                  </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <a class="modals" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#PatientDiagnosisModal"  href="">
                        <div class="panel-body"><img class="img-responsive  center-block" src="../img/diagnosis.png"></img></div>
                        <div class="panel-footer"><center>Patient Diagnosis</center></div></a>
                        </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

How to overcome to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has helper classes to center elements : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center

Add the class `center-block` to your images, it should do the trick:

```
<div class="panel-body"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="../img/diagnosis.png"></img></div>
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/70jjc5xw/1/)

---

If it's not working with the boostrap class, try adding your own `center-block` class in your css file and then add it to your images:

```
.center-block {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle for this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/jyqp0o9q/1/)

Comment: I don't have access to your pastebin right now (proxy...). Does my example works on you browser ? I just took your html code and added the `center-block` class to the images. It works fine for me.

Comment: Which browser do you use ? And does your pastebin contain your full code ? Because there is no html header with the inclusion of the bootstrap css file...

Comment: Check my edit, try to add your own `center-block` in your css. If it's not working and none of my examples are working on your browser, then you should stop using this outdated browser `;-)`

Comment: The same happened in Mozilla Firefox

Answer (score -1):

Instid you can use `<center>` tag to achive this. Here is a quick example.

```
<center><div class="row"><img src="your image"/></div></center>
```

Hope this Helps!

Comment: The `<center>` tag is not supported in HTML5, you should try to not use it `;-)`

Answer (score -1):

Write in the CSS:

```
.panel.panel-default { margin: 0 auto !important; }
```